# How to specify "binary" path for remote chromedriver in codeception?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, codeception, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use a remote chromedriver with codeception. I'm currently able to connect to the chromedriver, because if I don't start it, I get a different error (after a long timeout). However, the chromedriver isn't able to start chrome on that windows VM because it's not installed in the path it's searching it for. I tried to override it but can't find the way to setup codeception for that options.

Here's what I tried in my acceptance.suite.yml:

```
    WebDriver:
        host: 10.0.15.15
        port: 9515
        url: 'http://www.box.dev'
        browser: 'chrome'
        capabilities:
            binary: "C:\\\\Program Files (x86)\\\\Google\\\\Chrome\\\\Application\\\\chrome.exe"
```

I tried a couple variations over the binary format with \ \ \\ \\ and /. Chrome just don't show up... There isn't much "output" from the chromedriver so I'm going a little bit blind on that...

Answer (score 0):

The chromedriver should run on the host system. You have to start selenium with an option, which says selenium where the chromedriver.exe is located.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role node -hub http://www.box.dev:9515/register/grid Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="C:/Users/me/Downloads/chromedriver.exe"
```

Then you only need to say in your codeception configuration, that you want to use the browser chrome (it should be installed there).

Answer (score 0):

The acceptance.suite.yml that works for me on Windows looks like.

```
capabilities:
    chromeOptions:
        args: ["disable-infobars", "headless","disable-gpu", "window-size=1920x1080"]
        binary: "C:/Users/***/chrome.exe"
```